# A standalone SVG editor?

Tags: offline, image-editor, svg

I am seeking recommendations of a program that

- allows creation, editing and saving of files in .svg format
- allows standard editing including

  - drawing lines and shapes
  - filling areas with color
  - cropping
  - opening files saved (perhaps in only a few colors) as .jpg, .gif, etc. for pasting into the file being edited
- is not limited to the creation of diagrams
- can run standalone rather than on top of a web browser or otherwise online
- is free or at least shareware

Comment: Interesting that this question was never asked before.

Comment: Not free (which is why this is a comment), but both illustrator and sketch can work with svg and have all professional features you'd expect like layers, masking, custom shapes etc

Comment: @ThomasWeller Maybe because Inkscape is the very first result when you google "vector graphic editor". There even is a list of vector graphic editors above the results. Inkscape is the very first one in that list, too.

Comment: For which operating system?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

How about [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)? It is:

- free and open source,
- > has a perfectly compliant SVG format file generation and editing,
- can open a number of other vector formats, with the help of extensions,
- > can natively import most raster formats (JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc.) as bitmap images, but it can only export PNG bitmaps,
- as it is a downloadable software, it runs standalone.

Sounds like it could fit, so maybe worth giving it a try.

Comment: I wanted to give an addendum to the answer of Inkscape:
I use it all the time for my vector use. There are a Lot of handy features and panels to edit SVG. There is even a pane where you can view the underlying XML tags and edit attributes from there. This is great to doublecheck the stacking order of elements, see what objects are included in a Group, and even add JavaScript interaction as well.
I wish you luck with it!

Comment: Indeed, Inkscape is probably one of the best options out there.  The only significant complaint I've ever seen about it is that it doesn't do a great job of generating the most space efficient SVG files possible, but for most people that shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: if your concerened about eth resulting output.. you could always run it through a SVG optimiser.. see http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser or www.svgminify.com/ as examples

Comment: @ShoeLace Note that for some sectors and companies, uploading any files to external services is considered a big no-no for security and confidentiality reasons and can very well result in you getting reprimanded or even fired.

Comment: Indeed. Making that kind of application as a remote service is just irresponsible and user-hostile. If it really needs to be on the web (and have the nice features like being cross-platform, sandboxed), it could be a JS application that runs entirely client-side in the browser rather than asking you to upload your private data (or your client's/employer's/friend's/etc. private data) to some sketchy third party.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn regarding the creation of space efficient SVG files in Inkscape: its "native" SVGs are indeed quite fat (e.g. they include several Inkscape-custom tags), but there is an option to save "Optimized SVG" (it's another format in the Save As dialog) which produces much smaller output with a variety of options for further space saving. I've no idea how favourably it compares to external SVG optimizers though

Comment: @DaveJones The optimizer built into Inkscape is the SCOUR optimizer, which also exists externally.

Comment: FWIW, I pretty much use Inkscape for 90% of my vector illustration work. The only thing that keeps me from using it 100% is a lack of print color space management.

Comment: @NZall  true... then an offline version like https://github.com/tdewolff/minify maybe ? there are a few other opensource versions available

Answer (score 10):

As already mentioned I would go with Inkscape if you want a full featured SVG editor with great design capabilities and powerful tools.

If you want something simpler however, are looking for a web based solution or Inkscape is not available on your desired platform there is also [SVG Edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG-edit).

SVG Edit is a JavaScript browser based editor, that can be used both [online](https://svgedit.netlify.app/editor/index.html) or [downloaded for offline use](https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit)

[image]

It is admittedly less feature complete than Inkscape, but for simpler works it may suffice and be lighter on resources and more forgiving in terms of platforms.

There is also [Boxy](https://boxy-svg.com/) available for the Mac App store, Windows 10 Store, and as a Chrome App

Answer (score 4):

Any semi-decent vector editing application should fulfil your requisites (except being free). In addition to the [already mentioned](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/46364/26385) [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), [Gravit Designer](https://designer.io/) is a good choice (you can use it both in the browser or as a standalone app).

Comment: Inkscape doesn't require X Windows. It's multiplatform.

Comment: @BenCrowell It still requires [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) on macOS, which is no small bother.

Comment: @user137369: There is an Inkscape branch (`osxmenu`) which doesn't require XQuartz.

Comment: Inkscape no longer requires X (as of 1.0), so I’ve removed that from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use any plain text editor.  I use `mousepad`.  SVG is just an XML file with a well defined and stable DTD, analogous to HTML.  If you really want to be able to control your images, manually editing the XML is the only way to go.

Download and read the SVG specification, available here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/

That's the online version - the download links are in the first paragraph.

To view your edits, use a simple image viewer.  I use `geeqie`.

Alternatively, open the file with a browser using `file:///path/to/your.svg` for the URL.  A civilized operating system will give you the option to open with a browser by right clicking on the file.  Then, every time you save, click reload in the browser.  This is all offline - the browser does not need a network connection to view local files.

A browser is handy, because if you make a typo, the browser will tell you where it choked when parsing your file.  If you look at your text near that place there will be something obvious e.g. a missing close tag.

I use a composition cycle that works like this:

1) Copy/paste the basic SVG header and opening and closing tags - in the beginning, you can crib these from any `.svg` file - there are variations, and eventually you'll want to understand the differences, but to start it doesn't matter much.

2) Add some elements and save.

3) See if they look how you wanted - if not, adjust the data and/or the elements.

4) Repeat until you are happy.

Another tactic is to start with a `.svg` you found on the web that is close to what you want and modify it using a similar workflow.  When you do this, you will undoubtedly encounter files that were created with `inkscape`.

Files created by `inkscape` are cluttered with all manner of unnecessary rubbish.  You'll soon learn what is needed and what is not and be able to scrub an `inkscape` file with a few minutes of deletion editing.

Many `.svg` files from the web have the formatting removed.  There are many XML tidy programs that can restore readability.  I usually do it manually since SVG files are usually quite small - a single editing pass removes the clutter and restores formatting, seldom taking more than ten minutes.

The other activities you require are pre or post processing steps.  I use `gimp` for that.  If you can reduce a `.jpg` or `.png` to truly only a handful of colors, `gimp`'s SVG export facility does an astonishingly good job.  As a post processor, `gimp` can read your file and export it in any format you desire, and the image manipulation facilities are very complete.

What I'm advocating here is a more professional toolkit approach, in contrast to the usual consumer oriented monolithic program that holds your hand and tries so hard to prevent you from hurting yourself it prevents you from accomplishing what you want.  Yes, it is harder to start.  Yes, you will need to learn some new things.  Yes, you will encounter some difficulties.  But in the end, you will get the images you want in much smaller files.  You will also acquire valuable skills and deeper understanding along the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [OMGSVG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/). That link is the web front-end for testing, but it can also standalone on your pc as a Node application.
How to do this is explained on the [README](https://github.com/jakearchibald/svgomg) page on github.

This tool is for folks who want to alter the SVG with code (JavaScript programmers)