# An application to display only certain elements of an SVG

Tags: svg, graphviz

I am looking for an SVG viewer that allows me to select/toggle the visibility attribute of elements, preferably via point and click, but easy queries would be fine as well.

I've found [previous](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47773/real-time-svg-viewer) [SVG](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46362/a-standalone-svg-editor?rq=1) viewer questions, but none of them mention this functionality.

Ideally I would:

- open an existing SVG
- be able to show/hide a certain class of elements
- show/hide only elements that have an id starting with a keyword

Free is preferred, but if a paid solution exists I'm also interested.

The background is that I have a graphviz file [with layers](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/faq/#-how-can-i-use-drawing-layers-overlays) and I would like to easily toggle layer visibility when presenting the graph to other people.

[The jquery.graphiz](https://github.com/mountainstorm/jquery.graphviz.svg) repository has code that comes close, but it cannot select by node type or layer.

Comment: If it is about layers, Inkscape can do that. Not's not blazingly fast, unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunately the layers are not Inkscape layers, but graphviz layers, which translate to an svg node with the layername prepended to it.
When I open the SVG in Inkscape no distinct layers are shown.